# Application-specific audio settings

Tags: sound

Is it possible to **select the output device** and settings of each application, on an independent basis? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to control the playback and record levels of an application? You can control them through the sound menu>sound settings and the application tab. you could also install the gnome-alsamixer:

```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer
```

If you are referring to more specific control settings the applications you are using should provide that.